# Find the limit $\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ x^{3}y - 9y^{4} }{ x^{2} + y^{2} }$

Tags: calculus, limits

I find that this limit goes to $0$ but it's not right. $\displaystyle\lim_{(x,y) \to (0,0)} \frac{ x^{3}y - 9y^{4} }{ x^{2} + y^{2} }$

Comment: Why? What answer are you expecting? And why are the questions on the title and the post different?

Comment: It does go to zero, check for $y=0$, $x=0$, $y=x^2$ and $x=y$ you always get the same result, it is very unlikely that you'll find a different result with a different path

Comment: Why can't you just use L'Hospital's  rule for each variable independently? That being said what makes the limit not look like its 0?

Answer (score 2):

Switching to polar coordinates, we have:
$$ \frac{x^3y - 9y^4}{x^2 + y^2} = r^2(cos^3\theta sin\theta - 9sin^4\theta) $$
Since the term in parentheses is bounded, and $r^2 \to 0$, the limit exists and equals 0.

Comment: This is what I tried, but apparently the limit does not exist

Comment: @John What makes you believe that it does not exist?

Answer (score 1):

$$
\left|\frac{x^{3}y-9y^{4}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\le
\left|\frac{x^{3}y}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|+\left|\frac{9y^{4}}{x^{2}+y^{2}}\right|\le|xy|+9y^2.
$$